# Exception when connect to MySQL using Pomelo Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, mysql, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I've a class library project and it connects to MySQL using Pomelo Entity Framework core. But it gets this exception **An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseMySql' call.** when connect to Mysql database.

The issue can't not to reproduce because it only occurs in my client side and but not in my dev environment. The only difference between 2 environments is that I use Windows 10 and my client uses Windows 11.

Step working:

1. Create a class library for DAL has HQPCDbContext, MainUserConfiguration and entity file
2. Create another class library has Program.cs file (main project)
3. Reference the DAL project in main project

This is **DAL.csproj** file:

```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
       <PropertyGroup>
            <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
       </PropertyGroup>

       <ItemGroup>
            <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.17" />
            <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="5.0.4" />
       </ItemGroup>

   </Project>
```

This is **Program.cs** file:

```
string dbConnection = "server=localhost;port=3306;Uid=root;Pwd=mysql;database=test;"
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<HQPCDbContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseMySql(dbConnection, MySqlServerVersion.LatestSupportedServerVersion);
var _context = new HQPCDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
var user = _context.MainUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == "abc");
```

This is **HQPCDbContext** file:

```
public class HQPCDbContext : DbContext
{
    public HQPCDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new MainUserConfiguration());       
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<MainUser> MainUsers { get; set; }
}
```

And this is **MainUserConfiguration** file:

```
public class MainUserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MainUser>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MainUser> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("MainUser");
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);            
    }
}
```

What is this issue and how to fix it? Everyone please help me!

I'm using .Net5, Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql ver 5.0.4, Mysql ver 8.0.30, Windows 11

Comment: Post the actual full exception, not just parts of the message. You can get the full exception with `Exception.ToString()` or by clicking on `Copy Details` in the exception popup.

Comment: The very phrase `transient failure` means you can't guess when it occurs though, nor reproduce it easily. Perhaps the client's LAN is flaky? Or they connect to a cloud database over unreliable or slow internet connections? Their VPN as intermittent delays? Why not add the `EnableRetryOnFailure` call as the error message suggests?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, tks your comment. But because it only occurs in client so I just receive the error mess from them. I want to know what is happening first because need someone go onsite if adding EnableRetryOnFailure call

Comment: Also, cause they use DB in localhost so the machine is not connected with network

Comment: Post the error. Don't ask people to guess from the message. Besides, running a database and a web server on the same machine is not a good idea as each one is trying to steal CPU and RAM from the other. You may be getting this error because the database times out while you try to connect to it. Besides, you're using an *unsupported* version of .NET Core and a very old version of Pomelo. The earliest supported .NET Core version is 6. The current Pomelo version is 7

Comment: `The only difference between 2 environments is that I use Windows 10 and my client uses Windows 11.` Windows 10/11 are *client* OSs which means CPU, RAM etc are configured to give priority to the desktop user and apps. They even have a network connection limit. Have you tried to stress-test your application with a workload similar to the client's?

Comment: i hesitate to post this a little.  But CONSIDER (not just "blindly throw ~something at the issue)......adding "connection pooling" to your connection string..with a Min Pool size of 1.  (you will have to figure out a responsible Max Pool size).  But again, that can cause "other issues" if you don't deeply think about what connection pooling might do .. to your overall client-install.     see : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-pooling.html

Comment: I also agree.  you should probably upgrade to (LTS) (long term support) dotnetcore (target framework) 6.0 (you seem to have 5).. and try to get on a latest/latest version of the Pomelo library and entity-framework libraries.